# Multiple associations from one model to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: Job and User.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I want a job to have both an "owner" that refers to user and a list of users that are assigned to the job.

Basically, I want to be able to do:

```
job.owner # return user
job.users # returns users
```

What is the correct way to model this with ActiveRecord associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the magic with Rails associations is figuring out the class name for you. However, you can specify it yourself if you need to.

Here's what the schema should look like:

```
create_table :jobs do |t|
  t.integer :owner_id
end

create_table :users do |t|
  t.references :job
end
```

And here's what the models should look like

```
class Job < AR::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  has_many :users
end

class User < AR::Base
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Comment: To make it complete, you could also show how to setup User class, to properly define relationships, and what columns are needed (migration). Or link to material (guides.rubyonrails.org?) with more informations

Comment: What does the job schema look like? Does this association expect that Job will have a user_id or something like owner_id?

Comment: Found the answer here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference, you can specify it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: User
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_jobs, class_name: Job
  belongs_to :job
end
```

This way you have:

```
@user.job
@user.owned_job

@job.owner
@job.users
```

Also create columns like this:

```
class SomeMigration
  def change
    add_column :jobs, :owner_id, :integer
    add_column :users, :job_id, :integer
  end
end
```

You can read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to another model here, so users can have jobs in two different contexts – as job owners, and job users.

I'd try something like this:

```
# Setup user model (users own jobs)
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :user_job_subscriptions
end

# Setup job model
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_job_subscriptions
end

# Setup job subscription model (users can also have/subscribe to jobs)
class UserJobSubscriptions < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user, :job
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end
```

Also, here's an awesome video (it's a little outdated, but that's OK) that will help you understand the different types of associations available to you – and why/when to use them: http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

Comment: Is there any advantage of having the UserJobPublications vs. just having a user_id reference on job?

Comment: Well, if you're planning to store more data in job publications – sure, but, if you're just using it to join users to jobs, there's no need. I simplified the approach above. Maybe give this a try?